# Implementing own system call linux

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I got an assignment to implement my own system call and I have to use latest kernal v5.9.
Downloaded linux-5.9-rc8(even stable version is giving same error) and extracted.
Then cd into this directory.

```
mkdir hello && cd hello
```

Made a file hello.c and added the following code

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
asmlinkage long sys_hello(void) 
{
    //printk prints to the kernel’s log file.
    printk("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Made a Makefile and added the following code

```
obj-y := hello.o
```

Then cd .. and opened directory's Makefile and edited line

```
core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/
```

to

```
core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ hello/
```

In the file arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl, at the end of the file added

```
548     64      hello   sys_hello
```

In the file include/linux/syscalls.h, at the end and before the #endif statement added

```
asmlinkage long sys_hello(void);
```

Used default config with command

```
make defconfig
```

Finally

```
make -j4
```

Got the following error

```
ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xdc0): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_hello'
make: *** [Makefile:1162: vmlinux] Error 1
```

These steps I followed, copied from online tutorial sites, tried almost all the sites and still getting the same error on top of the wait time of 2-3 hrs to compile the kernel. For compiling the kernel certain packages are also required, I haven't mentioned them in the steps.

Comment: try changing the second column from `64` to `common` in `syscall_64.tbl` (just guessing)

Comment: Have you verified that you can build the kernel from sources, without making any modifications to the source code? This test determines whether the source code is complete and all build tools installed and configured properly. If the build succeeds without modifications, and fails *only* after src is modified, the problem is in the src modificatios... but if the build fails even before making any src changes, then the problem is an incomplete build system, maybe bad installation or a bad starting place. Always good to establish a known-good starting baseline before making changes

Comment: I have compiled the kernel without making any changes then its working fine. Only when I add code for custom system call it gives the specified error